# "Urban paths" in a Riemannian manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, oc.optimization-and-control

Fix a compact Riemannian manifold $M$, a base point $p\in M$, a basis $B$ for the tangent space $T_p$, and a destination $q$.

The metric on $M$ determines its Levi-Civita connection.

My goal consists of finding a short path from $p$ to $q$ of a special form: such a path must leave $p$ traveling along a geodesic lying in a direction contained in $B$ and, carrying $B$ along according to the connection, arrive at new point $p_1$; if $p_1\not=q$, then at $p_1$ the path must turn in a new direction belonging the the transported basis. The steps then repeat until finally we arrive at $q$ after a journey possessing a finite number of legs.  Call such a path *urban* (because we must stay on the "city streets" determined by $B$) unless the literature already has a name for this.

Clearly, with a bound on the number of legs, some urban path attains the
infinimum length of all urban paths with no more than that many legs.

My questions: without a bound on the number of legs, must some urban path still attain the infinimum?   If yes, can we get a bound, based solely on the dimension of $M$, for the number of legs in this ``urban geodesic''?

Answer (score 3):

Let us modify the problem a bit.
Consider all paths from $p$ to $q$.
For each path $\gamma$, transport the frame along  $\gamma$ and measure the $\ell^1$-length $\gamma$ --- the length of $\gamma$ in the $\ell^1$-norm provided by the frame.

Note that for urban paths the $\ell^1$-length coincide with the usual length

Now consider a path $\gamma_0$ from $p$ to $q$ which minimizes $\ell^1$-length.

Note that arbitrarily close to $\gamma_0$ there is an urban path with arbitrarily close length. 
So if $\gamma_0$ is a strict minimum and it is not an urban path then there's no chance of getting a minimum among the urban paths.

An example can be constructed the following way:
Take Euclidean plane and multiply its metric by conformal factor $1+(x-y)^2$;
the path $\gamma_0(t)=(t,t)$ satisfies the condition above.

Comment: I convinced myself informally that the hyperbolic plane works for this, and specifically that the path at an angle equidistant between two basis vectors in the frame is a strict minimum, but I don't have a formal proof.

Comment: @WillSawin I would think of formal proof only if there is an application --- I do not see one right now.

Comment: @AntonPetrunin Either I don't follow, or perhaps you meant $\ell^1$ where you write $\ell^\infty$.  Wouldn't the $\ell^\infty$ length from $(0,0)$ to $(1,1)$ in flat ${ R}^2$ equal 1, while no urban path could be shorter than $2$?

Comment: I don't know what counts as an "application," but I can explain my motivation.  Urban paths can be expressed independently of the $(M,g,B)$, and then $(M,g,B)$ imposes an equivalence relation on the set of urban paths (meaning when they arrive at the same destination). It seems to me that this equivalence relation captures $(M.g,B)$ and represents an intriguing alternative foundation for Riemannian geometry.  So I'd like to build a dictionary, e.g. figure out how to express curvature.

Comment: @DavidFeldman yes sure I will correct it

Comment: @AntonPetrunin: Your construction shows that there is a counterexample to 'urban paths with a bounded number of' turns' furnishing a minimum' for a modified problem, in particular, for a Finsler metric instead of a Riemannian one.  At first, I thought that you meant to suggest that this indicated that there would be a counterexample for the original Riemannian problem, but I don't see why this would be so.  Did you intend to suggest this?

Comment: @RobertBryant yes, it gives a counterexample for the original Riemannian problem --- did you read the 4th пaragraph?

Comment: @AntonPetrunin:  Thanks.  I did read the last paragraph, but it wasn't clear to me that you were using the Euclidean *Riemannian* metric.  It's clear that $\gamma_0$ is a geodesic in the Riemannian metric that you construct,but I'll have to convince myself that the calculation in the Finsler metric implies what you are claiming for the Riemannian metric.  Anyway, thanks for the response.

Comment: @RobertBryant >I'll have to convince myself that the calculation...
I look forward to your determination.

Comment: @RobertBryant look at the area bounded by $\gamma_0$ and an other path --- (const)x(it's square) is an apper bound on what you can save by rotating the frame, and (const')x(it's square) is an lower bound on difference of parallel $\ell^1$-length. If the path $\gamma_1$ is short, then const'>const.